# Running an excel macro from task scheduler

Tags: vba, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to run a macro using task scheduler and it looks like it executes the VBScript file but it doesn't actually execute any  of the code in the macro.

The pathway for the workbook is 
C:\Users\cdurrell\Desktop\Test Auto 1.xlsm

The macro is called TestAuto

And the Script file has the pathway 
C:\Users\cdurrell\Desktop\TestAutoScript.txt

I originally was using the following script file

```
'Write Excel.xls  Sheet's full path here
strPath = "C:\Users\cdurrell\Desktop\Test Auto 1.xlsm" 

'Write the macro name - could try including module name
strMacro = "Update" '    "Sheet1.TestAuto" 

'Create an Excel instance and set visibility of the instance
Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
objApp.Visible = True   '   or False 

'Open workbook; Run Macro; Save Workbook with changes; Close; Quit Excel
Set wbToRun = objApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath) 
objApp.Run strMacro     '   wbToRun.Name & "!" & strMacro 
wbToRun.Save 
wbToRun.Close 
objApp.Quit 

'Leaves an onscreen message!
MsgBox strPath & " " & strMacro & " macro and .vbs successfully completed!",         vbInformation
```

'

and it would make the excel workbook read only and not execute the code in the macro.

Then I took out the line

```
wbToRun.Save
```

and now it doesn't make the excel workbook read only but it still doesn't execute the code.

Any pointers or corrections are welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Are you running the Task Scheduler task under your user login?  Are you logged in when this runs?  If you just run the vbscript directly does it succeed in running the Excel macro?

Comment: Yes and yes. And I have it set to only run when logged in too. As far as running it directly, I can't get it to find the file so it won't attempt it. I don't know how to run it from command prompt so I'm sure it's my fault.

Comment: You can just double-click the vbs file.  Get that working before involving the scheduler

Comment: I get the error that it can't find the file. Is it possible it was moved, renamed, or deleted.

Comment: But I know that that is the correct pathway.

Comment: Are you 100% certain that the macro is 100% foul-proof and will never raise an unhandled error or pop a `MsgBox`? Because the task may never complete if that happens. Unattended execution of Excel / VBA is not a recommended scenario. If you have SQL Server Standard (and depending on what that macro does), consider leveraging SSIS instead of using macros.

Comment: The error is saying that the pathway is "C:\Users\cdurrell\Desktop\Test Auto.xls" and in the script file it clearly shows "C:\Users\cdurrell\Desktop\Test Auto 1.xlsm" So i don't know why it has the wrong pathway.

Comment: `xlsm` vs `xls`? or is that a typo in your comment?

Comment: positive that the macro is error free. It runs on its own just fine when not using the script file to execute it

Comment: The workbook is .xlsm  but the error is saying that it can't find the workbook but it has the name wrong and the extension wrong even though the code has it correct

Comment: Do you have "hide extensions for know file types" checked in your Windows Explorer options?  Your script has a txt extension when it should be .vbs ?

Comment: Try `Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` and `fso.FileExists(strPath)` in you script to make sure the file really exists before trying to open it.

Comment: The script is definitely .vbs  and I don't have it set to hide extensions.

Comment: I'm getting a new error now which states "Cannot run the macro 'TestAuto'. Macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled"

Comment: Fixed! The resolution was to leave the sheet name out of the macro declaration! Thanks everyone who helped me troubleshoot the issue. As always, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are still facing this issue, but I found my own solution since I was experiencing the same trouble. It is based on this old answer in **Super User** by **[squillman](https://superuser.com/users/2156/squillman)**:

https://superuser.com/a/579901

1. Open Component Services (Start -> Run, type in dcomcnfg)
2. Drill down to Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer and click on DCOM
   Config
3. Right-click on Microsoft Excel Application and choose Properties
4. In the Identity tab select This User and enter the ID and password of an interactive user account (domain or local) and click OK

Now, what else I needed to do?

5. Configure the scheduled task with the same account that I configured in step 4. *I tried with the service account and failed.*
6. Run whether user is logged or not.

After this, I was able to run it properly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it started working once I checked 'run with administrative privileges' in the task settings.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I have run macro enabled Excel code in the following manner.

In your Windows Task Scheduler Task Action

1. Program/script:
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE"
   Note the double quotes around the entire path to handle spaces correctly
2. Add arguments (optional):
   "C:\Users\cdurrell\Desktop\Test Auto 1.xlsm"
   Note double quotes around the entire Excel file path to handle spaces correctly
   Then in the Workbook_Open event, place code to run the macro TestAuto
3. If you need to pass arguments add them as below as a comma delimited list
   "C:\Users\cdurrell\Desktop\Test Auto 1.xlsm" Arg1,Arg2,Arg3

   Note the double quotes go after the xlsm, Not after the arguments

   Here is some sample code pertaining to retrieving Command Line Arguments

   ```
    Option Base 0
    Option Explicit

    ' Adapted from answer by Max Meng on Thursday, November 8, 2012 8:45 AM
    ' From: Passing a parameter to an Excel file when opening it RRS feed
    ' Link: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/bb9fa94f-a1d4-45cd-9279-b12e7a7e69c0/passing-a-parameter-to-an-excel-file-when-opening-it

    ' This is the command line delimiter in Windows Task Scheduler Actions.
    ' It is then followed by a comma delimited list of arguments to be parsed.
    '    <Exec>
    '      <Command>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE"</Command>
    '      <Arguments>"C:\Path1\Path2\FileSystemWatcherManager.xlsm" /e/CalledByTask,UseTestEmails</Arguments>
    '    </Exec>

    Private Const m_ParmFlag As String = "/e/"
    Private Const m_DoubleQuote As String = """"

    Declare PtrSafe Function GetCommandLine Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetCommandLineW" () As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function lstrlenW Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString As Long) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (MyDest As Any, MySource As Any, ByVal MySize As Long)

    Public Sub GetCommandLineInfo(Optional vArguments As Variant, Optional ByRef sExcelAppFile As String = vbNullString, Optional ByRef sExcelFile As String = vbNullString)
    Dim lCommandRaw As Long, lIndex As Long
    Dim sCommandLine As String, myParam As String, sTemp As String
    Dim vEmpty As Variant, vParts As Variant
        vArguments = vEmpty
        sExcelAppFile = vbNullString: sExcelFile = vbNullString

        lCommandRaw = GetCommandLine
        sCommandLine = GetCommand(lCommandRaw)

        If InStr(1, sCommandLine, m_ParmFlag, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            vParts = Split(sCommandLine, m_ParmFlag, -1, vbTextCompare)
            vArguments = vParts(UBound(vParts))
            If Not IsArray(vArguments) Then
                sTemp = vArguments
                vArguments = Split(sTemp, ",")
            End If
            sCommandLine = Trim$(vParts(LBound(vParts)))
        End If

        lIndex = InStr(2, sCommandLine, m_DoubleQuote)
        sExcelAppFile = Left$(sCommandLine, lIndex)
        sExcelFile = Trim$(Mid$(sCommandLine, lIndex + 1))

        lIndex = InStrRev(sCommandLine, " ")
        myParam = sCommandLine
        If lIndex > 0 Then
    ''''''        myParam = Trim$(Mid$(sCommandLine, lIndex + 1))
        End If

    ''''''    Call MsgBox("Argument: '" & myParam & "'.", vbOKOnly Or vbInformation, "Command Line Argument(s)")
    End Sub

    Private Function GetCommand(Cmd As Long) As String
    Dim Buffer() As Byte
    Dim StrLen As Long
        If Cmd Then
            StrLen = lstrlenW(Cmd) * 2

            If StrLen Then
                ReDim Buffer(0 To (StrLen - 1)) As Byte
                CopyMemory Buffer(0), ByVal Cmd, StrLen
            End If
        End If

        GetCommand = Buffer
    End Function
   ```